# How to hide extension's request from chrome inspector?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Can i hide request made by chrome extension like 'seoquake'? i can't see the requests to bing, fb, pinterest etc from inspector like screenshot below:
[image]
but if use 'fiddler web debugging' tool i can see it like screenshot below:
[image]

How to do that? and can i unhide that requests?
it's use super permission from chrome to seoquake or all dev can do that with our own javascript?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to hide things from the inspector.

Comment: The extensions have a separate background page. Inspect it and you'll see the requests.

Comment: @Barmar seoquake found the way, but i dont know

Comment: @wOxxOm how to inspect it? but i dont think so, cause other extensions except seoquake can be inspected on every page i opened.

Comment: Not all extensions have background pages. For those that do open it on [chrome://extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029) page after enabling its developer mode as shown in the link.

Comment: @wOxxOm you are alright, thanks you very much...

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer, please go to chrome bug tracker and let the chrome dev team know we need this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239401

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open Chrome DevTools. In the network tab filter box, enter the string `-scheme:chrome-extension` (see screenshot below):

[image]

This is case-sensitive, so make sure it's lowercase. Doing this will hide all resources which were requested by extensions.

Comment: Although this does work and it's the best we've got right now, unfortunately it's unsustainable as I don't really want to type all that in every time I fire up devtools :/ there should be a checkbox for this

Comment: Well, it's better than anything else so this option is definitely a godsend!